# Question with display graphic and description from signature using itext v5.6.xx

Tags: itext

I'm learning digital signature from [this book](https://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/2018-12/digitalsignatures20130304.pdf), it's very helpful. When I read the "Custom rendering mode" section, I see this one:

> RenderingMode.GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION—this will split the signature field in
> two and add an image on one side, the description on the other side.

I have tried and found the result is to divide 2 parts by left and right, I'm wondering if there's a way to make it 2 parts according to top and bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the source code](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/develop/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfSignatureAppearance.java#L943) of the iText `PdfSignatureAppearance` class, iText decides whether to split left/right or top/bottom based on the height and width of the appearance rectangle: If it is strictly higher than it is wide, the area is split top/bottom. Otherwise it's split left/right.

Comment: If the rectangle's width > height, this displays the image on the left and the data on the right. Is there any simple way to display the image on the right and the data on the left?

Comment: @LHF *"Is there any simple way to display the image on the right and the data on the left?"* - I think you'll have to create such an appearance yourself (using a custom n2 layer).